# App crashes with WKWebView and UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, wkwebview

I'm building an app using Storyboard. And I also use UINavigationController.

One of the views has a tool bar and there's a barButtonItem which directly connected to another view as "show" segue, and the view is correctly shown.

The view to be shown creates WKWebView's instance. In this view, WKWebView works fine.

But when, I tap the back button of NavigationBar, the app crashes and I can't cat the exception even I set All Exceptions.

In the viewDidLoad of the view using WKWebView,

```
WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
configuration.allowsAirPlayForMediaPlayback = YES;
configuration.requiresUserActionForMediaPlayback = YES;
configuration.allowsPictureInPictureMediaPlayback = YES;

webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero configuration:configuration];
webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
webView.allowsLinkPreview = YES;
webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = YES;
[_childView addSubview:webView];

webView.navigationDelegate = self;
webView.UIDelegate = self;
// Autolayout
NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(webView);
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[webView(>=0)]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[webView(>=0)]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

// Propertiesの監視
[webView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"estimatedProgress" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
[webView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"title" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
[webView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"loading" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
[webView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"canGoBack" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
[webView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"canGoForward" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

I created the WKWebView's instance.

How can I avoid crashing when I tap on UINavigationController?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps, your web view tries to send some delegated methods to controller that already doesn't exist. To quickly check, try to set nil to delegates on viewWillDisappear. If this is the case, you should think how to free web view  when controller disappears.

Comment: Nick, thank you for your advice.
I set those delegate to nil, but still app crashes.

And I found that I need to remove Observers.

Then the app works fine.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WKWebView was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it, I think you should remove the observer when deinit. such as:

```
deinit 
{
    webview.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "estimatedProgress")
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!